# how to enable/disable the dropdowns by selecting either of the dropdows below?

Tags: jquery

how to enable/disable the dropdown Country and State ,When i do select an option of country option the State dropdown should be disabled and the other side Viceversa(When i do select the dropdown of State the dropdown of Country should be disable.
and also hot to move to the other JSP page when i click a submit button in JSP page syntax?
     
        
        jQuery select / dropdown box example

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <h1>jQuery select / dropdown box example</h1>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#country").change(function () {

     if($("#country option:selected").val()){
         // disable the dropdown:
         $('#state').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     } else {
         $('#state').removeAttr('disabled');
     }

      });});
    </script>
    </head><body>

    <select id="country">
    <option value="None">-- Select --</option>
    <option value="China">China</option>
    <option value="United State">United State</option>
    <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
    </select>
    <select id ="state">
    <option value ="AP">AP</option>
    <option value ="SP">SP</select>
     </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: If you disable the state dropdown, how will a user ever be able to change their mind a select a state instead of a country?  You might want to rethink your UI.

Comment: if the User selects the Country option dropdown ,State dropdown should be disabled . Is there is way that again can we Enable the State dropdown

Answer (score 0):

Hiya **Working demo** : http://jsfiddle.net/vAJuc/ **&** I have also made this for you if you want disable enable on specific country choice: http://jsfiddle.net/vAJuc/4/ (in this particular case if you select china it will disable just for example)

So you had the HTML wrong I have corrected (Missing end option tag etc...) in the jsfiddle as well as the code below; Also this might be good help; http://api.jquery.com/change/ (Play around and read query api.

Below code will give you good start for you r submit button I would recommend improve the question or might ask again with this code. Hope below stuff will be helpful. :)

**JQuery Code**

```
$(function() {

   $("#country").change(function () {

     if($("#country option:selected").length){
         $('#state').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     } else {
         $('#state').removeAttr('disabled');
     }
   });


});​
```

**// OR // If you want it to behave disabled on specific country select see below: (In this case if you select china it will disable**

```
$(function() {

   $("#country").change(function () {

     if($("#country option:selected").val() == "China"){
         $('#state').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
     } else if ($("#country option:selected").val() == "Malaysia"){
         $('#state').removeAttr('disabled');
     } else {
         $('#state').removeAttr('disabled');
     }
   });


});​
```

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>

    <h1>jQuery select / dropdown box example</h1>

    <select id="country">
       <option value="None">-- Select --</option>
       <option value="China">China</option>
       <option value="United State">United State</option>
       <option value="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
    </select>
    <select id ="state">
         <option value ="AP">AP</option>
        <option value ="SP">SP</option>
    </select>

        </body>
    </html>​
```

Hope this helps, cheers

Comment: Can we make blank when the other dropdown is Selected .For example if the country dropdown option is selected ,then the state option should be blank .viceversa.

Comment: Hiya you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/vAJuc/8/ ; so now if you select you will default yo nothing on the second drop down; you can improve the fiddle, hope this helps, cheers

Comment: but if i have 100 of customers in the single dropdown , is there any way that to show the other dropdown blank.

Comment: Yeah, its simple; you will do the same logic, but with dynamic object! :) lol if my answer helped atleast accept it. If you can send me more info. I might be guide you to right direction; Cheerios!

Comment: Actuall i am retriveing the values from the database for the dropdows below.So,i major task is ,when the user clicks any of the option from the dropdown of Country ,then the State option should be blank and viceversa.Would you please help me .

Comment: $("#country").change(function () {

   $("#country option:selected").val();
       $('#state').val('blank');});
        $("#state").change(function () {
 $("#state option:selected").val();
        $('#country').val('NONE');
  
  });